# Using open(filename,'r') in function - should I close it again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file

I usually use the 'with open' where I don't have to worry about closing the file again, but I want to make a function which opens the file:

```
def SafeOpen(filename,mode):

    try:
        infile=open(filename,mode)               

    except IOError as error:                                                        
        print('Can not open file due to error:',str(error)) 
        sys.exit(1)    

    return(infile)
```

Should I close the file again?

Edit:

For example - should I do like this:

```
infile=SafeOpen(filename,'r')
for line in infile:
    print(line)
infile.close()
```

Am I able to use 'with open' instead?

Comment: your function is equivalent to `open` function, so yes, you have to close the file. And you should let exception propagate, since open in python is already safe (because uncatched exception exits the process as well)

Comment: You can use `with` because your function returned the file object. The context manager is created for the file object and python doesn't care where it came from.

Comment: The `with` takes whatever object it is presented and calls its `__enter__` method (or raises an error if there is no such method). `open` is a function just like `SafeOpen` and the both return a file object (`io.TextIOWrapper` for text files) with an `__enter__` method.

Answer (score 3):

you can call your function in a `with` statement:

```
with SafeOpen("test","r") as f:
    c = f.readline()  # OK
c = f.readline()  # error: operation on closed file
```

as soon as you exit the block, the file will be closed. The `__exit__` function applies to the `f` file object, no need to change your function (of course don't use `with open` in your function!).

That said, it's often enough to let the `IOException` propagate and quit your program. Using `sys.exit` can break applications calling your module (which will have to intercept `SystemExit` exceptions instead)

Comment: Thanks! Calling my function in a with statement makes sense

Comment: But I will have to change my SafeOpen function then, right?

Comment: Im just confused because in the function I return 'infile' but in the 'with' statement I also open it as infile, so isn't that doing the same thing twice?

Comment: no. Your function does the open (and no other statement does), and maps to `f`. The `f` object is "associated" to the `with` block. `f.__exit__` is called when exiting the block, which calls `f.close`

Comment: But isn't my return(infile) unnecessary then, because I never use it?

Comment: it's used in `SafeOpen("test","r") as f`. The return value of `SafeOpen` is assigned to `f` when entering the block.

Answer (score 0):

If you return the file, you'll eventually need to close it with

```
return_val.close()
```

If you don't return the file, the variable will automatically be released... although it's bad practice in any case not to use `with`

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand. I just edited my post and I would of course prefer to use with